# Class constructor: set value from other value, reference and value types

Tags: c#, class

I have such class:

```
class Data
    {
        public int[,] G;
        public int[,] R;

        public Data(int[,] G, int[,] R)
        {
            this.G = G;
            this.R = R;
        }

    }
```

and such class:

```
class Calculation
    {
        public Data data;
        public Form1 f1 { get; set; }
        public int[,] G;
        public int[,] R;
        public int[,] R_def;
public Calculation(Form1 f1, Data data)
        {
            this.f1 = f1;
            this.data = data;
            this.G = data.G;
            this.R = data.R;
            this.n = G.GetLength(0);
            this.R_def = data.R;
}

public bool ant_calc(int start_)
{
... some calculation, where in result my R element's get 0;
but nothing is done with R_def;
}

public void calculate(int start__)
        {
            int first_edge = start__;
            for (int o = 0; o < 10; o++)
            {
                bool a_c = ant_calc(start__);
                while (a_c != true)
                {
                    a_c = ant_calc(start);
                    start__ = start;
                }
                f1.listBox1.Items.Add("------");
                L_max = 0;
                 R = R_def;
                passengers = 0;
                where_been = new int[n, n];
                curr_R = new int[n, n];
                start__ = first_edge;
            }
        }
```

and form part:

```
private void loadData()
        {
            this.reader = new Reader("test1.txt");
            Data data = new Data(reader.G, reader.R);
            Calculation calc = new Calculation(this, data);
            calc.get_shortest_path();
            calc.construct_new_graph();
            calc.calculate(0);
        }
```

my question is in that, how in such line: R = R_def; i could set my first R value, which i send from form? I didn't make any edit's in code with R_def, but it's behavior is same as R do, why? How could i set R_def as frozen, that there i contain default data.R value, and never change it?

if something is not clear, write in comments...

Comment: If you want to copy aray values I suggest you use `Array.Copy()`.

Comment: @ja72 this doesn't help, but loop help

Comment: You must be doing it wrong then. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20974375/380384) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

`R = R_def` assigns a *reference*, not a value. In other words, `R` and `R_def` then point to the same array in memory. You should read about reference types and value types in some beginner's C# book.

Comment: hm, maybe it would be easy to write soultion here...

Comment: or delete you answer, and i will delete question

Comment: R_def = new int[n, n];
            this.R_def = data.R;   something in that way is not good, how then?

Comment: @brabertaser1992 well, there's [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). IIRC, if you'd had classes in the array they would be copied by reference though, so you should still be aware of how references/values work.

Comment: @Default array.copy didn't solve my problem... "you should still be aware of how references/values work"  i will read, but i need answer now and quick(

Comment: No, there's no "now and quick" here. You have to learn the very basics before proceding. Blindly copy&pasting someones code from an answer is not a solution, it's a workaround.

Comment: why some people are so angry... i didn't won't that you give all code...  why some people without doubt help, and someone just: go and read... ok, i will go and read, just remember, sometime ago, you was "noob" too, and earth is a boomerang... just note, i need this only one time for 5 year, i'm not a coder also.

Comment: I'm not angry. I'm giving you the best possible advice. This is really a very basic stuff, like "chapter 2" of any C# tutorial. This site isn't here to substitute that tutorial.

Comment: @OndrejTucny i understand, just my problem, that all solution in web didn't work for me, maybe becouse i set value's un class

Comment: You should understand SO isn't here to debug someone's code. You *have* to do your part. I've indicated where's the bug in your code. It's your turn to learn and the debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you use `Array.Copy()` to copy values between two 2D arrays:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Init and fill array
    int[,] R=new int[10, 20];
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
        {
            R[i, j]=20*i+j;
        }
    }

    // Init new array
    int[,] G=new int[10, 20];
    // Copy 2D array
    Array.Copy(R, G, R.Length);
}
```

Comment: and what? )) so work's on me too, but see that i send from other class etc data?

Comment: When you copy the data and modify `R` then `R_def` will remain unchanged.

Comment: i need so! unchanged!